# Mod analytics traffic sources & keywords list requests fail

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools

XHR requests from `/admin/analytics` to the following urls fail (500, Oops! Something Bad Happened!):

- `/admin/analytics/run-report`
- `/admin/analytics/keyword-list`
- `/admin/analytics/traffic-source-list`
- `/admin/analytics/traffic-sources`

Reproduced on Mythology, Politics and Programmers.

Comment: Apparently, Anna is already on this: https://twitter.com/aalear/status/603317977191161857 (thanks ChrisF)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We were using an old library to fetch the data from Google Analytics, which was using a deprecated authentication method.

[Geoff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/2/geoff-dalgas) changed us over to a different one.